# Unable to compile; no valid source files were found using grunt responsive-images

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I am using [grunt responsive-images](https://github.com/andismith/grunt-responsive-images) on a Jekyll website.

A related [issue](https://github.com/andismith/grunt-responsive-images/issues/100) on GitHub is now closed but I still get this error. Both the `src` and `cwd` point to a single `test.jpg` image.

When I run `grunt responsive_images:posts` I get **Unable to compile; no valid source files were found.**

**Sample of gruntfile:**

```
  ...
  responsive_images: {
    posts: {
      options: {
        engine: 'im',
        sizes: [
          { name: 'small', width: 320, quality: 80 }
        ]
      },
      files: [
        {
          expand: true,
          src: [ '_assets/posts/**{.jpg}' ],
          cwd: '_assets/posts/',
          dest: 'img/'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  ...
```

**Grunt dependencies:**

```
{
  "name": "corporate-programmer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.6",
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^2.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-responsive-images": "^0.1.7",
    "grunt-shell": "^1.3.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.5.0"
  }
}
```

**Sample of file structure:**

[image]

**Verbose output:**

[image: Verbose output when running task]

```
> npm -v
> 2.7.4

> npm list imagemagick -g
> └── imagemagick@0.1.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src` is usually relative to the path defined in `cwd`, update your `src` value to `**/*.js`

```
responsive_images: {
    posts: {
      options: {
        engine: 'im',
        sizes: [
          { name: 'small', width: 320, quality: 80 }
        ]
      },
      files: [
        {
          expand: true,
          src: [ '**/*.jpg' ],
          cwd: '_assets/posts/',
          dest: 'img/'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! That introduced a new error though but I think it solved that one. How do I know if ImageMagick is installed correctly? `>> spawn identify ENOENT
Warning:
Please ensure ImageMagick is installed correctly.
`brew install imagemagick` or see http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php for more details.
Alternatively, set options.engine to 'gm' to use GraphicsMagick.
 Use --force to continue.`

Comment: Imagemagick isn't installed on machines by default, you'll need to install it using `brew install imagemagick` if you're on Mac.  Windows/Linux -you'll need to look up those directions

Comment: Thanks, I'm installing on Windows now. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Working! Thank you for all your help!